# Early park admission to Universal's island of adventure

Tags: florida, amusement-parks, orlando, universal-studios

It's my understanding that if you're staying at one of Universal's hotels that you get a Universal Express Unlimited pass and early park admission.

I'll be staying at Loews Royal Pacific Resort from Feb 10 - Feb 12. According to https://www.universalorlando.com/Resort-Information/Theme-Park-Hours.aspx the park hours are from 9 am - 7 pm that Friday.

At what time can I enter the park with the early park admission?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Universal Orlando Early Park Admission**](https://www.universalorlando.com/Resort-Information/Early-Park-Admission.aspx)

> Early Park Admission enables all on-site hotel guests, Preferred Annual Passholders, Premier Annual Passholders and other select approved groups, to make the most of their day with:
>
> - Entry to one theme park an hour before its scheduled opening
> - Access to select attractions at the designated theme park
>
> The available theme park, attractions, times, etc. for Early Park Admission vary based on operational considerations. Times are subject to change without notice.